# Setting WeekDay/Weekend/Days selected in my Logic

Tags: android

**The Logic :**

I am implementing a logic in which when a button is clicked , a dialog box opens with multiple check-boxes representing the days of week.
When user selects any one day from dialog , the same wil be shown in my button with in a trimeed format. eg: if "Monday" is slected "Mon" will be displayed in my button.

**Problem Faced:**

When the user selects multiple days (say : "Monday" , "Tuesday") i want all those selected days to be displayed in the button.

**In the below code , i have implemented the logic when a single day is selected. eg: When "Monday" is clicked in the dialog's checkbox list, the button is set with the text as "Mon".
I don't know how to code the logic for displaying multiple days.**

- **Logic for the problem :**

**If "Monday" && "Tuesday" is selected in the checkbox list, then set button text to "Mon,Tues"**

i don't know how to implement the above logic.

Someone please provide me the code. Thanks in Advance

**The Code:**

```
Dialog dialog;
        final String[] items = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" , "Saturday" , "Sunday"};
        final ArrayList itemsSelected = new ArrayList();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Select The Days : ");
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null,
                new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int selectedItemId,
                                        boolean isSelected) {
                        if (isSelected) {
                            itemsSelected.add(selectedItemId);

                           if (items[selectedItemId] == "Monday"){
                               RecurrencePicker.setText("Mon");
                               int day = 2;
                           }else if (items[selectedItemId] == "Tuesday"){
                               RecurrencePicker.setText("Tue");
                               int day = 3;
                           }else if (items[selectedItemId] == "Wednesday"){
                               RecurrencePicker.setText("Wed");
                               int day = 4;
                           }else if (items[selectedItemId] == "Thursday"){
                               RecurrencePicker.setText("Thu");
                               int day = 5;
                           }else if (items[selectedItemId] == "Friday" ){
                               RecurrencePicker.setText("Fri");
                               int day = 6;
                           }else if (items[selectedItemId] == "Saturday"){
                               RecurrencePicker.setText("Sat");
                               int day = 7;
                           }else if(items[selectedItemId] == "Sunday"){
                               RecurrencePicker.setText("Sun");
                               int day = 1;
                           }

                        } else if (itemsSelected.contains(selectedItemId)) {
                            itemsSelected.remove(Integer.valueOf(selectedItemId));
                        }
                    }
                })
```

Comment: Can't you do something like

    RecurrencePicker.setText(RecurrencePicker.getText() + " Sun");

Comment: ok. But how do i check the condition for multiple check boxes selected? What would be the if statement syntax?

Comment: when i try to check the below way it throws an error saying "The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, String"
    `code`
    if(items[selectedItemId] == "Sunday" && "Saturday"){
                             
                            }

Comment: If it's only for button text, you can just use the getText() method and it will append the current choice to it. You'll also want to do something when it's deselected.

Comment: if you know how to use Recurrence picker dialog box, please educate me with the same. I am implementing currently the above logic because i don't know to use Recurrence picker dialog box. please provide me the syntax and logic. Thanks in advance

Comment: To be honest, I'm not 100% familiar with this particular library. I would imagine that if there is a RecurrencePicker.setText(String) method, there would be a RecurrencePicker.getText() method, and if so, would only require simple string manipulation to accomplish your goal. I'm sorry I'm not much help :(

Comment: will try out your idea. Thanks for your interest in helping me out :)

Comment: This is your complete code or any other code have you. Please show your complete code here to give you a right solution

Comment: That's the complete part of code in which i'm facing problem. from this i will be passing only the int value to other methods. in order to get the int value according to the user selection i am using if statements. when user selects, for example "Monday" & "Tuesday" , i want to execute the RecurrencePicker.setText(String) statement to set the text of button as "Mon","Tue" . This is the entire scenario of my problem.